# How do I garbage collect the Elixir REPL, iex?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

In python if I'm playing around with the REPL I can force garbage collection with `import gc; gc.collect()`. How do I do the same with Elixir's `iex` REPL?

Example before large variable binding:

[image]

So around 700M of RAM used and 300M of swap.

After large data binding to variable `xx` (fetches 500 timeseries of 7000 structs each from database):

[image]

So now around 2.2G used with 500M swap. Now rebinding xx to something small:

[image]

But memory used hasn't really changed. Still 2.2G RAM and around 500M of swap. However if I quit IEX:
[image]

Back to under 400M of RAM used. So the big data binding which was re-bound, wasn't garbage collected within `iex`. How can I force it to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's info about this here: https://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/GarbageCollection.html

Maybe just try doing:

```
:erlang.garbage_collect()
```